# CakePHP - REST POST functionality not working with default mapping

Tags: php, cakephp, rest

I am new to CakePHP and am attempting to configure my web app to use REST.

I am using CakePHP version 2.0.4.

Following the CakePHP Cookbook, I have entered the following into the routes.php file ('Apples' pointing to the ApplesController.php controller):

```
Router::mapResources('Apples');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

and in the controller itself (ApplesController.php), I have added the following component:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

Also in the controller, I have an add action which echo's a string (as follows):

```
function add() {
    echo 'The add action has been called';
}
```

Finally, I created a view (index.ctp located in app/View/apples/) which uses a HTML form with the method POST and the action "/apples/" to submit.

```
<h2>Home<h2>
<form action="/apples/" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now according to the the CakePHP Bakery (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rightwayindia/2010/01/11/restful-web-application-development-in-cakephp), the mapResources should automatically map POST to the 'add' action of the controller specified in the routes.php file, therefore when the button is clicked, should echo the string in the add action.

This only works when you change the action parameter in the HTML (in index.ctp) to:

```
<form action="/apples/add" method="post">
```

and explicitly point to the add action.

I may be wrong, but I thought that by configuring REST in the routes.php file should automatically map the specific REST methods to the actions such as add, edit, delete etc.. (stated on the web page linked above) to the controller stated in the paramater of the mapResources function.

I have also tried custom REST routing but this is also not working.  However, It would be nice for it to work with default mapping rather than customising it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem has been solved.

This code:

    Router::mapResources('Apples');
    Router::parseExtensions();

needs to be entered above the code:

    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';

in the routes.php file otherwise the code won't be reached.

I am surprised this isn't documented in the Cake cookbook!

Comment: This must be a 2.0 issue as in my 1.3.x apps those two calls are the last 2 lines in my routes.php . Also, please close the question. :)

Comment: it is documented in book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Comment: Those lines are also present in the default routes file of cake 2.x