# cakephp rest api POST request invokes index() rather than add()

Tags: php, json, api, rest, cakephp

I'm working on a cakephp JSON REST api --

I'm following the REST tutorial at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html and testing everything via the Chrome extension "Advanced REST Client"

The only route I can get to function as expected is the index() via a GET request -- which returns me an array of my test data (as expected)

When I POST to attempt to create a new record, I receive a 404, similarly I added some test data to my DB in order to try a GET Request for a recipe by ID (a 36char UUID field) and the request routes to the index() function.

I'm receiving the following response when I try to do anything but a simple get request:

```
{
code: 404
url: "/users/d8d9701e-2f6e-11e3-af16-2513f388d17e"
name: "Action UsersController::d8d9701e-2f6e-11e3-af16-2513f388d17e() could not be found."
}
```

The request here is a GET to users/d8d9701e-2f6e-11e3-af16-2513f388d17e

In my routes.php file:

```
Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'update', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => true)
));

Router::mapResources('users');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

My UsersController.php looks like : http://pastebin.com/bDxRLbTP

*NOTE* The commented Access Control Rule seems to have no effect on my issues. I've tried it with and without the control rule, which I'm not 100% positive exists in the right place, anyway. But I thought the POST wasn't working because of some CORS issues. However, it would not explain the GET issues when trying to find a specific record.

According to the tutorial I feel like I shouldn't actually need the Router::resoureMap function, but I threw it in anyway just in case. I've also tried putting it below the Router::mapResources call -- but in the tutorial it says:

> "By overwriting the default resource map, future calls to mapResources() will use the new values."

So I'm pretty sure it needs to be called before calling mapResources()

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that apparently I had my functions in the wrong area of the routes.php file.

As per: [CakePHP - REST POST functionality not working with default mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601829/cakephp-rest-post-functionality-not-working-with-default-mapping?rq=1#comment10675782_8601829)

In routes.php I had the following as my last lines of the file.

```
Router::mapResources('users');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

They needed to be moved above this line:

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```